# How to get the user's current speed using Google Fit's API?

Tags: java, android, google-maps, google-fit

Working with the Google Fit API at the moment and having a bit of trouble with the Sensors API. I'm trying to get user's current speed for my app's workouts but the documentation is a bit confusing.

In this code snippet is an example from Google's info page:

```
Fitness.SensorsApi.add(
            mClient,
            new SensorRequest.Builder()
                    // Optional but recommended for custom data sets.
                    .setDataType(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)// Can't be omitted.
                    .setSamplingRate(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS).setAccuracyMode(SensorRequest.ACCURACY_MODE_HIGH)
                    .build(), mListener3)
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<Status>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(Status status) {
                    if (status.isSuccess()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Listener registered!");
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Listener not registered.");
                    }
                }
            });
```

//Adding a Listener

```
mListener3 = new OnDataPointListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataPoint(DataPoint dataPoint) {


           final float speed = dataPoint.getValue(Field.FIELD_SPEED).asFloat();

            runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    Log.i(TAG, "In Speed" + speed );
                    speedTxtView.setText("" + speed );

                }
            });


        }
```

Currently, I am getting all other datatype values like distance, heart rate ,step count and current activity but unable to get user's current speed.
Is i am doing correctly?

Comment: Have you checked whether the speed datasource is avaliable by the SensorsApi.findDataSources method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could try the [basichistorysessions sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-fit/blob/master/BasicHistorySessions/app/src/main/java/com/google/android/gms/fit/samples/basichistorysessions/MainActivity.java) from Google Fit Github repository.

sample code:

```
  // Build a session read request
        SessionReadRequest readRequest = new SessionReadRequest.Builder()
                .setTimeInterval(startTime, endTime, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .read(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
                .setSessionName(SAMPLE_SESSION_NAME)
                .build();


// Invoke the Sessions API to fetch the session with the query and wait for the result
                    // of the read request.
                    SessionReadResult sessionReadResult =
                            Fitness.SessionsApi.readSession(mClient, readRequest)
                                    .await(1, TimeUnit.MINUTES);

                    // Get a list of the sessions that match the criteria to check the result.
                    Log.i(TAG, "Session read was successful. Number of returned sessions is: "
                            + sessionReadResult.getSessions().size());
                    for (Session session : sessionReadResult.getSessions()) {
                        // Process the session
                        dumpSession(session);

                        // Process the data sets for this session
                        List<DataSet> dataSets = sessionReadResult.getDataSet(session);
                        for (DataSet dataSet : dataSets) {
                            dumpDataSet(dataSet);
                        }
                    }
```

You can refer to this [reading fitness data using sessions](https://developers.google.com/fit/android/using-sessions#read_fitness_data_using_sessions) section for more information.

Comment: how do i get speed without startTime and endtime ?

Answer (score 0):

To get the speed, dataSourceType should be derived. The following works for me

```
        Fitness.SensorsApi.findDataSources(mClient, new DataSourcesRequest.Builder()
            .setDataTypes(DataType.TYPE_SPEED)
            .setDataSourceTypes(DataSource.TYPE_DERIVED)
            .build())
            .setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<DataSourcesResult>() {
                @Override
                public void onResult(DataSourcesResult dataSourcesResult) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "Result: " + dataSourcesResult.getStatus().toString());
                    for (DataSource dataSource : dataSourcesResult.getDataSources()) {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Data source found: " + dataSource.toString());
                    }
                }
            });
```

Comment: how it work please  explain i want to get speed and step